Force library to use specific version of another library kotlin android
Am using com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.23.0 library in my android project that seems to internally using   another library filament-utils-android:1.21.1. Everything is working fine upto this point.
Developer has stopped providing support to scene form library. I need to use latest version of filament library in my code. If am explicitly adding latest version of  filament-utils-android i.e 1.31.4 in gradle file sceneform library also started to use filament 1.31.4 instead of 1.21.1. App is crashing at runtime because a file named as KTXLoader in filament 1.21.1 has been renamed to KTX1Loader in version 1.31.4.
Getting ClassNotFoundException : Didn't find com.google.android.filament.utils.KTXLoaded
Is there is any way I can force the sceneform library to use 1.21.1 version of filament library instead of 1.31.4 that is explicitly as implementation in gradle file.
If have tried to use following constraint but still its referring to version 1.31.4.
implementation("com.google.android.filament:filament-utils-android:1.31.4")
implementation("com.gorisse.thomas.sceneform:sceneform:1.23.0") 
constraints{
    // added this line to force sceneform library to use filament 1.21.1 instead of 
    //1.31.4
    implementation("com.google.android.filament:filament-utils-android:1.21.1")
}

Don't want to use ScreenView instead of sceneform library as it will require many changes in current code.
Let me know if you need more information about the issue.
Please help.

Please consider using Sceneview as described in the repository README.
If you still want to use unmaintained version, just fork sceneform-android repository and update required codes (updating dependencies and renaming class in your case).
Then you can package the forked repository using Jitpack and use it. 

Using screenview instead of sceneform will require lot of changes in code. Is it possible to force sceneform to use 1.21.1 version of filament.

@napster I don't think you can use multiple versions of the same library. There may be workarounds like relocating dependencies using Shadow plugin by shading one of the versions to a different package. But, these workarounds may still have conflicts with transitive dependencies. I recommend forking the repository and editing the code.
